# Loop involving randoming and accessing sheets data gives errors often

Tags: python-2.7, random, google-sheets, tweepy

I'm making a bot that accesses data from a google sheet and tweets data in a particular cell. Previously I was running this from a local CSV file using CSV module but decided to make it on sheets so I don't need to push to Heroku every time I add more data.

```
while True:
    try:
        while True:
            sheet = client.open("Lyrics").sheet1
            rand = random.randint(1,int(sheet.cell(1,11).value))
            d = sheet.cell(1+rand,1).value
            #api.update_status(status = d)
            print(rand)
            print(sheet.cell(1+rand,1).value)
            time.sleep(10)
    except:
        print("Error")
        time.sleep(10)
```

I tried the original code (not posted here) first but I got a lot of errors so I started dissecting everything to see where error could be. Some of the code 
(`print(sheet.cell(1+rand,1).value)`) seems redundant but I couldn't get it to print `d` because of some TypeError. I stopped the tweeting part to see if somehow that was causing it but it doesn't seem to be from twitter. This code works as expected

```
while True:
    try:
        while True:
            sheet = client.open("Lyrics").sheet1
            rand = random.randint(1,int(sheet.cell(1,11).value))
            d = sheet.cell(1+rand,1).value
            api.update_status(status = d)
            print(rand)
            #print(sheet.cell(1+rand,1).value)
            time.sleep(10)
    except:
        print("Error")
        #time.sleep(10)
```

so I'm guessing it has something to do with calling sheets?

I don't absolutely need to see the data because I'm not going to see the console anyway but I would like to know and understand why this is happening.

Comment: Can I ask you about your question? 1. Can you provide the error messages? So I asked about it. 2. Do you use gspread? I thought that you might use gspread from your script. 3. If the value of `sheet.cell(1,11).value` is constant in the loop, how about declaring it at out of the loop? I'm worried about [the quota](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits).

Comment: 1.  I should've put that in the code instead of printing "Error", my bad. I can't seem to replicate it effectively just now but if it does turn up I've edited the script to print the error and i'll update here. 2. I do 3. It counts the number of non-empty rows in the sheet so I can select a random row and tweet the data from that row, so if someone updates the sheet I need it to be in the loop. Even with the quota, my actual script tweets every hour so I doubt it would affect it that way. I'll take the ```        sheet = client.open("Lyrics").sheet1``` out of the loop  and see what changes.

Comment: @Tanaike I tried this locally and I'm not getting any error.

```sheet = client.open("Lyrics").sheet1
#tweet
while True:
    try:
        while True:
            n_lyrics = int(sheet.cell(1,11).value)
            rand = random.randint(1,n_lyrics)
            #d = sheet.cell(1+rand,1).value
            #api.update_status(status = sheet.cell(1+rand,1).value)
            print(rand)
            #print(sheet.cell(1+rand,1).value)
            time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e: print(e)```

Comment: The error was auth session expiring. I've included it inside the loop now, it works.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.